# Callback hooked to post_updated firing on new posts as well

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions, archives, documentation

**Context:** I'm using a plugin that allows me to add author boxes throughout my site ([Simple Author Box](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-author-box/)), while providing an easy way for any user to update their social media links and profile pictures. I figured I could also leverage that plugin to dynamically show the team members in the site's about section.

However, I didn't want to have author archives for the team members that won't be publishing any posts in the future (designer, myself etc.), so I used the solution from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74924/disable-author-pages-for-specific-users) as a starting point to disable specific users' author archives and from there I created a few additional functions in order to automate that functionality (author archives are now automatically being disabled/enabled according to the number of posts each user has published).

One of these functions is hooked to `post_updated`, which according to [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/): "Fires once an **existing** post has been updated." [emphasis added]

Here's the function's code (please forgive any lack of good practices, I'm new to PHP and not an experienced programmer):

```
/* 
* This function does the checks and the actual value update, if needed.
* It's called from inside the callback.
*/
function maybe_update_author_archive_status($user_id, $published_posts, $author_archive_disabled) {
    if ($published_posts == 0 && $author_archive_disabled != 'on') {
        update_user_meta($user_id, '_author_archive_disabled', 'on');
    } elseif ($published_posts != 0 && $author_archive_disabled != 'off') {
        update_user_meta($user_id, '_author_archive_disabled', 'off');
    }
}

/* 
* The callback itself.
*/
function maybe_update_author_archive_status_on_post_update($post_id, $post_after, $post_before) {
    if($post_before->post_status != 'publish' && $post_after->post_status != 'publish') {
        return;
    }
    
    $old_author = $post_before->post_author;
    $new_author = $post_after->post_author;
    $authors = array($old_author);
    
    /* If the post author has changed, I might need to update both author archive status */
    if($new_author != $old_author) {
        $authors[] = $new_author;
    }

    foreach($authors as $author) {
        $user_id = intval($author, 10);
        $author_archive_disabled = get_user_meta($user_id, '_author_archive_disabled', true);
        $published_posts = count_user_posts($user_id);

        maybe_update_author_archive_status($user_id, $published_posts, $author_archive_disabled);
    }
}
add_action('post_updated', 'maybe_update_author_archive_status_on_post_update', 10, 3);
```

However, to my surprise (and delight actually), it's also firing when I create and publish a new post. Can anyone explain me why? Under which circumstances this function wouldn't be fired? Even though this is the behavior I desired and everything is working as I wanted it to, this is not what I expected it would happen after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> also firing when I create and publish a new post

If you mean something like, you clicked the "Add New" button (which brings you to the post add new page at `/wp-admin/post.php`), and then you composed your post and finally hit the "Publish" button, then it's actually normal for the `post_updated` hook to get fired twice *or more*.

Why so or what happens is:

- After you clicked the "Add New" button, WordPress will automagically create a post with the `auto-draft` status (`post_status = auto-draft`).
- While composing your post, WordPress will *auto-save* the post so that you don't lose what you've composed thus far, and for each auto-save, the `post_updated` hook will be fired. And note that, during an auto-save, the post status is set to `draft`.
- And after you hit the "Publish" button, WordPress updates the post (with the status changed from `auto-draft` *or* `draft` to `publish`), and then the `post_updated` hook will be fired once more.

So as you could see, the hook could get fired at least twice when you manually create and publish a post.

But if you do that programmatically, e.g. using [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), then the hook will not be fired. Note though, if you have plugins or custom code in your theme, the hook might be fired, e.g. a code that runs via [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) and modifies the post slug then call [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/):

```php
// In a default WordPress setup/installation:

// This will not fire the post_updated hook.
$id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_title'  => 'Just testing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
) );

// And this will fire it, but just once.
wp_update_post( array(
    'ID'           => $id,
    'post_content' => 'Sample content',
) );
```

And I think you might want to execute your code only if the post is not being auto-saved, either as an auto-draft or [revision](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/).

So for that purpose, you can check if the constant `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is defined and that it's true-ish:

```php
// In your function (maybe_update_author_archive_status_on_post_update()), at the top:
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sally CJ, that clarifies things a lot! I was thinking about this after posting the question and doing additional research, and came across the `wp_insert_post()` code. There, the `$post_before` parameter is set to `null` if it's not an update, what worried me because the way I wrote it, my function seems it would might try to access an object property of something that is not an object yet (`$post_before`). Wouldn't that return an error? Or that magically initially created `auto-draft` post is what actually gets stored in that variable? Also, thank you for the additional tips.

Comment: If it's not an update, the function will not run the `post_updated` hook. :) But in my answer, I was telling you that the hook is indeed fired only if the post is being updated and not created, however, what makes the hook runs when you *create **and publish*** a post manually (via the admin UI) is the background actions as explained in my answer. So you can safely assume WordPress itself will not pass `null` as the `$post_before` value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!