# Disable Author Archive just for certain roles in bulk

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, users, archives

Hi I have a lot of users that have the role in wordpress as "Buyer" I want to be able to disable these users archive page so it is not public but I want to keep public users that have the role as "Agent". Is there a easy way to do this in bulk at all?

I found #chrisguitarguy plugin at [Disable author pages for specific users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74924/disable-author-pages-for-specific-users/407648#407648) very good but you have to disable the user one at a time and it is absolute nightmare to do this if you have alot of users.

Does anyone have a solution at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is to do a conditional redirect on `template_redirect` action. In the action callback, check that the request is for an author archive of the specified role and if it is, then do the redirect.

```
function my_disabled_author_archive_role() {
    return 'buyer';
}

add_action(
    'template_redirect',
    function() {
        // Is this an author archive?
        if ( ! is_author() ) {
            return;
        }
        // Does the author have the specified role?
        $author = get_queried_object();
        if ( ! in_array( my_disabled_author_archive_role(), (array) $author->roles ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // Redirect to somewhere
        if ( wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ) ) {
            exit;
        }
    }
);
```

If you want to exclude the role also from the default WP sitemap, then filter the users sitemap query args.

```
add_filter(
    'wp_sitemaps_users_query_args',
    function($args) {
        $args['role__not_in'] = my_disabled_author_archive_role();
        return $args;
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Antti thx alot for helping me I'm a total newbie to coding I was wondering where abouts in #chrisguitarguy plugin do I put this thx

Comment: Hi Antti can you help me at all mate i cant seem to get it to work thx

Comment: @PaulBriggs The example I posted is actually something you wouldn't add to the code in the other answer. This can be added to the `functions.php` file or as a custom plugin, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/. This code categorically disables the author archive for the defined role without settings.

Comment: Thx Antti well i tried to add it to function and make plugin it didn't work thx for the help anyway I dont want to take up any more of your time thx